# Volume/Fire bakes incorrectly to texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

I'm working on a Dungeon Crawler game with pixel textures. For this is make 3D objects in Blender and bake them to textures using planes I put around it, the same way you would bake high-poly meshes to textures for low-poly meshes.
I was making a torch and though it would be cool if I could use the Blender fire simulation to make the fire and smoke.

So I modelled the torch and learned to make fire from some tutorials. When I render a screenshot it looks exactly like what I want:
[image: Torch Render]

The fire is visible and even the wisp of smoke can be seen. (Cycles Renderer btw)

When I try to bake this to a texture however it looks nothing like that:
[image: Render Result]

On the left you can see the bake result, where the fire is replaced by a black box (the domain) with a projected texture of the fire. The four torches are seen from the front, 45° to the right, and the bottom two are the same sides again from 45° upwards. Margin is set to 0. This particular bake is "diffuse", but all others have similar results (normal, AO, etc.). Always like there is a box instead of the fire. On the right you have the torch model and fire domain with voxels.

What I want there are the flames and smoke to show up, both as semi-transparent pixels. Just like in the normal render.

The domain is the problem, but I don't know what exactly. I only have a volume shader on it and nothing else. And again, normal rendering works without a problem.

Comment: I don't know if fire simulations can be baked to textures, but anyway, why don't you use a four camera setup around the simulation instead?

Comment: I'm not baking it from 4 sides, but 8. 16 if you consider the 45° upwards ones (not sure yet if I'll use that in the game). The cameras would also make the pipeline harder. As it is I have one "cage" model that has all the sides mapped to a texture and I can render 16 sides with one button press. Especially with animations this would be paramount.

Comment: You need to render out the fire to an image sequence or set of images, you can't bake it to an image iirc.

Comment: Well, if baking is not possible, simulated fire/smoke died for my purposes. It's easier to just do it with separately rendered particles (of just the fire) than to use cameras and fuse the images together by hand. With 8 sides and animations the workload would just grow exponentially. :(